# Gender-unspecific pejorative for somebody selling themselves for personal benefit (not prostitution)

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, offensive-language

What would be alternative words for *whore* which do not primarily reference women? In this case by *whore* I do not mean a prostitute, but a person who is willing to sell themselves out for personal benefit. For example, how *whore* is used in the following sentence:

> He is such a whore, willing to do anything for positive publicity.

Answer (score 3):

> ...a person who is willing to **sell themselves out**...

A sellout?

> someone who does something that does not agree with that person's beliefs or values especially in order to make money
>
> - Angry fans called him a sellout when he started appearing in television commercials.
>
> [Learner’s Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/sellout)

It has a negative connotation but not as much as *whore*. It’s also extremely gender-neutral.

Comment: A sellout is often someone who caved under pressure. They didn't get up in the morning and think I'm really going to sellout today. A whore, metaphorical or otherwise, is thought to solicit.

Comment: I think sellout does have a similar meaning to "whore" within that context, but it does not carry the same intensity. Is there perhaps a substantially stronger word? I also agree with @PhilSweet that the meaning of "whore" within that context is somewhat more nuanced.

Comment: @PeterSantorin ...A *fucking* sellout?

Answer (score 2):

Commented by [Weather Vane](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/240807/weather-vane)

> In that context, "whore" is gender-neutral. Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/whore).
>
> > 1.2 A person who is regarded as willing to do anything to get a particular thing – he's a shameless publicity whore.

Comment: I understand, but I feel when the word "whore" is used within this context, it still primarily derives its meaning from a woman soliciting sex. "He is such a whore" clearly alludes to comparing him to a women prostitute.